# Is it a typo in Jensen's inequality?

Tags: jensen-inequality

I am reading a book where it is written:

For any $n \geq 1$, $E(|x|^n) \geq (E(|x|))^n$

I understand that it is simple apllication of Jensen' inequality for function $f(x) = |x|^n$, but I have some question about right side of the equation. Shouldn't it be $(|E(x)|)^n$ instead of $(E(|x|))^n$? Apparently these are quite different.

Comment: @gammatester so what?

Comment: @gammatester If $x = 1,-1$ with equal chance, then $|E(x)| = 0$, while $E(|x|) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is an application of Jensen's inequality to the convex function $\varphi(t)=t^n$ and the integrand $x \mapsto |x|$:
$$
\left( \int |x| \, d\mu(x) \right)^n \leq \int |x|^n \, d\mu(x).
$$

Comment: In the book it is written $|t|^n$

Comment: It is pretty much the same. You apply the convex function to $|\cdot|$, so the integral is non-negative.

Comment: @Siminoire, If $x = 1,-1$ with equal chance, then $|E(x)| = 0$, while $E(|x|) = 1$. I dont understand what shall I use?

Comment: In the statement, there is only the expectation of $|x|$. Now apply the convex function $\varphi(t)=t^n$ to $|x|$. Voilà.

Comment: It seems like you dont understand what I am trying to say. 1) $E(|x|^n) \geq (E(|x|))^n.$  2)  $E(|x|^n) \geq (|E(x)|)^n$. 1 and 2 are different, which one is correct? 1 or 2

Comment: What do you believe? Notice that $E(|x|) \geq |E(x)|$.

Comment: I believe in 2, because this is what comes out of direct application of Jensen inequality. Author writes stronger inequality as you have mentioned

Comment: Inequality 2 follows from inequality 1. Since 1 is true, they both are true.